# CSS Box-Shadow Animation Technique?

Tags: css, css-animations

So I've been doing a ton of skulking around on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) and have found a lot of awesome demos, particularly on the CSS front.  What I'm seeing consistently on the CSS front though is often utilizing the box-shadow property to produce crazy looking animations/graphics, [this is an example of what I'm talking about](http://codepen.io/Simonclavey/pen/njwvy).

Now, I'm guessing these people aren't doing this entirely by hand, and that they're using some kind of graphic design application to render the animation/graphic into valid CSS.  Is there an application(s) that does such a thing?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Why do you think that? How do you know that he did not grind it out with just css? Its just three or four static images. Not that its easy mind you (I would never have the patience), but assuming he used some sort of converter is not true I think.

Comment: I think that for exactly the reason you just described, I would never have the patience for it, and it's an occurrence I've seen happening more and more so I assumed there was some app I've never heard of that was aiding the process.

Comment: Well you can always email the author and ask him yourself. There is no such tool that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another author over on Codepen has released a little PHP library that converts images to CSS making use of this technique, however all the images it produces seem to crash Chrome's inspector. Not entirely sure why.

https://github.com/jaysalvat/image2css

**Edit:**
I just had Chrome finally respond and the code it produces doesn't seem greatly optimised.

Answer (score 1):

Here is his description from the actual code.

> Peanut butter jelly time banana.
>
> Using @joshnh's box shadow technique I have animated the banana
>   through just CSS.